# Why can't I use Ctrl+` as prefix in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am able to use ` as prefix in tmux.

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix `
bind-key ` send-prefix
```

But that key is very useful for other purposes, so I am trying to use Control+that_key and that doesn't work.

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-`
bind-key C-` send-prefix
```

gives me:

```
.tmux.conf: bad key: C-`
.tmux.conf: unknown key: C-`
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this not allowed for some reason?

Comment: On my systems, Ctrl+backtick does not seem to produce anything, and can presumably therefore not be used in a key binding... but I'm no expert in those things.  The correct syntax in `tmux` would be ``set -g prefix 'C-`'``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @Kusalananda
in the comments (and [this mostly unrelated Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908850/11810933)), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> typically returns an ASCII `NUL`/`0` in most terminals.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and (very oddly) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> do the same.

@Kusalananda also mentioned a Vim trick that appears to also work in Tmux:

```
set-option -g prefix C-@
```

Which I've confirmed works.  Note that, as a result, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> will then also work as prefix, assuming that nothing else in the OS or terminal captures them instead.

Comment: The `Ctrl-2` thing, this is why you may see NULs represented as `^@` in some places (in Vim, for example).  The `@` is `2` shifted.

Comment: @Kusalananda Well that changes the answer a bit ;-).  Thanks!