# expand alias commands of .bashrc before it gets executed in terminal

Tags: bash

I am a noob at this.

```
alias gc = git commit -m
```

I want:

- After typing `gc` in terminal
- press `space` and it will turn into `git commit -m`
- if i don't want that, press `esc` 
  and it turn into previous `gc`
- correct that suppose `gca` and press `space`

You get the idea.

Any solution for this?

PS: Tried the `shopt` option `shopt -s expand_aliases` 
If i write `gc`, it should turn into `git commit -m` in terminal 
but it doesn't.

Comment: Note that the syntax for the alias is wrong, you can't have spaces around the `=` and if you have spaces in the command, the command needs to be quoted. So your alias should be: `alias gc='git commit -m'`. Now, do you also need to see this `gc`  automatically expanded to `git commit -m` before execution? Can I ask why? Is it just to see it or is it so you can do something else? (If we understand why you want this, we can give a better answer).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I want to see it.

Comment: OK, but please explain why. You want to see it in order to be able to do something else. Maybe you want to see it to be sure before running. Or maybe you want to be able to edit it before running. We need to know what the final objective is in order to be able to give you a good answer. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: updated. plz check

Comment: I see. That will require a tool, I think, it won't be easy. The `expand_aliases` option isn't relevant here, that is just to make aliases available where they would not normally be available (in scripts, for example).

Comment: I wonder.. if unix community people can help me out :(

Comment: `abbr -a` sounds like a `fish` thing. Are you using fish or bash?

Comment: sorry.. yeah i used fish for abbr -a . fish shell already has half of the feature i mentioned in this post. But i want bash's one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be assuming that you have an alias in the `bash` shell, like

```bsh
alias gc='git commit -m'
```

and that you want to expand this on the command line before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.

You can do this by calling the Readline function `alias-expand-line`.  This is easiest done by "binding" a key combination to trigger that function.  Below I do that, choosing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> fairly arbitrarily (it just need to not collide with any other key combination that I commonly use):

```bsh
bind '"\C-xa": alias-expand-line'
```

After giving that `bind` command, you can start typing some command like so:

```bsh
$ gc "my message"
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> at any point on the line would expand the `gc` alias and turn that into

```bsh
$ git commit -m "my message"
```

The `bind` command would typically be put into your `~/.bashrc` file or wherever you put customisations for your interactive shell.

Readline functions can't "un-expand" aliases, but you could use <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+_</kbd> to undo the expansion (or bind the `undo` Readline function to some other key combination of your choice).

Comment: Can't we make some function or something to do that?

Comment: @MegaBang It's unclear what "that" refers to.

Comment: by `that` i meant `un-expand aliases`

Comment: @MegaBang See added bit at the end of the answer, regarding "undo".

Comment: please help me expand the alias bind to `ctrl+space` key

Comment: @MegaBang On some systems, using `\C-@` might work. On my macOS system, that is hijacked by the terminal, so I can't test it. You can also use `\M- ` (note the space at the end) to use `Alt` in place of `Ctrl`.  See the answer to the following question why binding `Ctrl+Space` is (or might be) an issue: [Why can't I use Ctrl+\` as prefix in tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/700532)